# Trouble using Source Han Sans in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I am currently using Microsoft Office 365 and I have been using Source Han Sans for a while with no problems, with Source Han Sans Light set as the default font on Microsoft Word. Recently, however, for reasons I don't know, I've become unable to apply any of the other weights to English characters without having to go into the Font dialog box and manually changing the Latin font into the desired weight of Source Han Sans to match the Asian font.

For example, when I highlight text containing Japanese, Chinese, and English, then try to change the font from Source Han Sans Light to Source Han Sans Bold using the font drop-down in the ribbon, only the Japanese and Chinese are affected, while the English remains unchanged. Upon opening the Font dialog box, the drop-down box for the Latin font is empty.
[See screenshot...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ97e.png)

I have tried setting the Latin font to "(Use Asian text font)", as well as hitting the "Set as Default" button afterwards, but to no avail.

I do not have this issue on PowerPoint and Excel.

Comment: What's your detailed Word version and build number? I am using Office English version and there is no Source Han Sans Light font. Click File > Account > About Word to check the version number.